# Why is chunk written length = 1023 and not 1024?

Tags: c#, arrays, stream, binaryfiles

*(wondering if i need a holiday)*

I am writing from a stream to a file. My chunk size is 1024

```
    int chunkSize = 1024;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[chunkSize];
```

I am testing pause and resume operations. Im my test, I am only writing one chunk.

My source file is 4096KB.

When I test how long the written file is, it has a length of 1023, not 1024. Why is it not 1024?

```
FileInfo partFile = new FileInfo(fullPath);
Console.Write(partFile.Length); //1023, not 1024!?
```

Code reference.

```
int chunkSize = 1024;
byte[] buffer = new byte[chunkSize];
int chunkCount = 0;

bool streamComplete = true;

using (FileStream writeStream = new FileStream(tempFullPath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
{

    do
    {
        chunkCount++;

        if (request.MaxChunks != 0 && request.MaxChunks < chunkCount)
        {
            streamComplete = false;
            break;
        }

        int bytesRead = request.FileByteStream.Read(buffer, 0, chunkSize);
        if (bytesRead == 0) break;

        writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    } while (true);


    writeStream.Close();
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the 'bytesRead' variable? Was it 1023 there, or 1024?

Comment: And if it was, why would it be?

Comment: From documentation here, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.read(v=vs.110).aspx 'An implementation is free to return fewer bytes than requested even if the end of the stream has not been reached.'

Comment: @MxyL: It's a stream implementation. It's at liberty to decide as it goes along how much it's willing / ready to give back to any read requestors. There's not contract that says it *must* give you exactly the number you asked for.

Comment: @Valamas-AUS Then I think you have your answer, see a fuller answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to suggest that even though you *requested* 1024 bytes, you actually got back 1023, and you can check `bytesRead` to verify this.

This is allowed by `FileStream` implementations. See documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

> The Read method returns zero only after reaching the end of the
>   stream. Otherwise, Read always reads at least one byte from the stream
>   before returning. If no data is available from the stream upon a call
>   to Read, the method will block until at least one byte of data can be
>   returned. **An implementation is free to return fewer bytes than
>   requested even if the end of the stream has not been reached.**

Your code is still correct, in that it only stops reading when zero is returned. But you can't expect every chunk read from the file to be exactly 1024 bytes - as you can see, it's not necessarily always the case.